# Как получить ID элемента в List состоящего из GameObjects[] по имени объекта в c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, list

У меня есть список из объектов c# (Unity):

`List<GameObject> possibleCharacters = new List<GameObject>();`

Как мне получить ID нужного объекта по его имени?
Дело в том, что я получаю это имя из другого списка и, например, получив имя "gotName" найти его в списке объектов possibleCharacters с таким именем и получить его ID. Пробовал как-то через **IndexOf()**, но ничего не получается. Подскажите кто в курсе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте Llnq:
Поиск первого элемента с указанным значением выбранного поля

```
possibleCharacters.FirstOrDefault(element=>element.Name=="<value>").Id
```

Comment: Не подошло - все время ругается на .Id, а без него выдает просто то же имя. Но, я все таки нашел решение с помощью **FindIndex()** и выглядит оно очень похоже: **possibleCharacters.FindIndex(element => element.name == value)** - возвращает id элемента в списке!

Comment: Но он возвращает не Id, а индекс элемента в конкретном массиве.
У типа GameObject вообще есть поле id?  В описанном мной способе, результатом выражения становится сам объект GameObject, а через точку можно обратиться к любому его свойству и методу

Comment: Я изначально получается не правильно выразился - мне нужен был именно индекс элемента в массиве. В любом случае, спасибо за наводку - по итогу я справился ))